# Adding a link to a very restricted section on a Wordpress Theme

Tags: javascript

I'm using STEAM theme - which brings in pre-built sections with various limitations.
The sections can be enabled, or disabled, but not added to, or edited.

We've decided to add a special link to the shop on the site, in one of the sections, and the one closest to the purpose allows:
1 - a header of x number of characters
2 - a sub-header of x number of characters
3 - a background pic.
These are displayed in a pre-formatted fashion.

It does not take html / widgets / shortcodes.

So the workaround is this JS

```
`$(document).ready(function(){
var block = $(".logo-third-section");
block.click(function(){
window.location = $(this).find("a:first").attr("href")
});
block.addClass("clickable");
block.hover(function(){
window.status = $(this).find("a:first").attr("href")
}, function(){
window.status = ""
})
});`
```

This is the only script we've found that actually renders the top line of text (the header in the section) clickable, but the link resolves to https://example.com/undefined
not to https://example.com/shop

(I'm moments away from redirection /undefined to /shop though...)

This script doesn't allow for the definition of the destination URL.

How do I add the URL in?

Comment: What is the `href` attribute of `a:first` set to?

Comment: I think we would need to see the snippet of html that get's output that this js is targeting to truly debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) with just the few templates you need altered? This is how WP intends you to make modifications to the output of your site, not doing hacky things with JavaScript after it makes it to the front end.

Using a child theme is much more sustainable to make long-term changes to your theming. Much more manageable than either a slew of javascript functions crammed in random corners, or worse, trying to edit the theme directly, just to have all the changes overwritten when you need to update the theme.